# Admob banner not filling up full screen

Tags: xcode, admob

My app was just released the other day. When I downloaded it to an iPhone 6 I noticed the admob banner didn't fill the full screen (look at the attached picture). The banner works fine on an iPad and iPhone 5 but isn't working correctly on the iPhone 6.

Here is my code I am using for the banner:

```
_bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];

_bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                               self.view.frame.size.height -
                               _bannerView_.frame.size.height,
                               _bannerView_.frame.size.width,
                               _bannerView_.frame.size.height);


_bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ID";
_bannerView_.rootViewController = self;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

[_bannerView_ loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:_bannerView_];
```

Does anyone see any problems or know how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance[image: admob_banner]

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to create Admob Banner. It worked fine in iPhone6 also.

```
-(void)createBannerAds
{
    //set up banner coordinates to display at the bottom
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,self.view.frame.size.height -kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait.size.height);
    self.adBanner = [[[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait origin:origin] autorelease];

    self.adBanner.adUnitID = ADMOB_ID;
    self.adBanner.delegate = self;
    [self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[@"600ecccd6a1c2a4750952facf253ea2f"];

    [self.adBanner loadRequest:request];
}
```